# errors popped out when using find and -exec for bash command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Below is the list of directories.
I want to remove all directories under those named started with "dummy_" and "log", which were created earlier than a year ago.
In other words, I want to delete those directories named by date.

-log

- table_a

  - log1

    - 2022-01-01

      - hi.py
    - 2022-01-02
  - dummy_a

    - 2021-10-10

      - hello.txt
    - 2022-01-01
    - 2022-02-02
  - dummy_b

    - 2020-11-11

      - hey.docx
    - 2021-03-28
- table_b

  - log1

    - 2022-01-11
  - log2
  - logger
- table_c

  - dummy3

I've tried the following bash command to echo those directories but those errors popped out.
(I don't wanna remove all the directories so I used "-exec echo {} ;" to test instead)

What I expected it to show was

```
log/table_a/log1/2022-01-01
log/table_a/log1/2022-01-02
log/table_a/dummy_a/2021-10-10
log/table_a/dummy_a/2022-01-01
log/table_a/dummy_a/2022-02-02
log/table_a/dummy_b/2020-11-11
log/table_a/dummy_a/2022-02-02
log/table_a/dummy_b/2021-03-28
log/table_b/log1/2022-01-11
```

So i used the following command but there were some problems in different scenario

1.
`find log/*/ \( -name log* -o -name dummy_* \) /* -type d -mtime +365 -exec echo {} \;`

Result:

```
find: /Applications: unknown primary or operator
```

2. Then I tried another two methods
   `find log/*/ \( -name log* -o -name dummy_* \) -type d -exec find {} -type d -mtime +365 -exec echo {} \;`
   `find log/*/ \( -name log* -o -name dummy_* \) -type d -exec find {} -type d -mtime +365 -exec echo {} \;\;`

Result:

```
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
```

I feel like the second command is more close to what i expected but i don't know what's wrong with it.

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Appreciate it!

Comment: it works if i separate them into two commands:
find log/*/log*/* -type d -mtime +365 -exec echo {} \;
find log/*/dummy_*/* -type d -mtime +365 -exec echo {} \;

But I wanna know how to combine it, thx!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you can do is use regex with find to search all the directories named by date older than one year, pipe that data to grep to filter the required pattern, and feed that output to xargs for removal.

```
find . -regextype sed -regex  '.*[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}' -type d -mtime +365 | grep -E 'log*|dummy_*' | xargs rm -rf
```

I suggest that you please check the output of the earlier command first to ensure that only required files are deleted.